# This is my LWC and I want some flexibility in it

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lwc-oss

I want flexibility so that in the first row it ends with 105 and in the next row it starts with 201; it means it automatically creates a row start with initials 1,2,3 and it means if it ends with 105, it can leave one blank box and start the next row with 201.

[image]

```
<lightning-card>
<div class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-bottom_medium">
    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-m-bottom_small" style="margin-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;">WING SELECTION</h2>
    <lightning-tabset>
    <template for:each={wingRecord} for:item="field">
        <lightning-tab onactive={handleActive} data-id={field.Id} label={field.Name} id={field.Id} key={field.Id}></lightning-tab>
    </template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
            <lightning-layout class="slds-wrap" flexibility="auto" multiplerows="true">
                <template for:each={floor} for:item="flt">
                <lightning-layout-item key={flt.value} size="12" flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                <div class="flatcls">{flt}</div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_11-of-12">
    <lightning-layout class="slds-wrap" flexibility="auto" multiplerows="true">
        <template for:each={record} for:item="flt">
            <lightning-layout-item key={flt.Id} size="2" padding="around-small">
                <div id={flt.Id} data-id={flt.Id} class={flt.Flat_Status__c} onclick={handleFlatSelection}>{flt.Name}</div>     
                <!-- //onmouseout={hideData} onmouseover={showData} -->
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr Unknown, could you please share the code that you've already got?

Comment: I added the code 
@Felix van Hove